# Cloning an specific image selected by the user?

Tags: javascript, html, image, clone, double-click

Hi and thanks in advance for reading!

I'm having a little trouble with JavaScript (well, I kinda actually *don't know* how to handle it).

My page shows various images, and I want them to be duplicated (cloned) to a specific div - but only the ones the user selects (by double-clicking). But there are a lot of images, so I can't just give a ID to each one.

Is there a way for the image to say "Hey I'm the image X" to the script, or something? ;_;

Also, how can I make the cloned images be non-clonable, just letting the user clone the images that were originally in the page (even if he/she can do it a unlimited amount of times)?

I really don't understand much of JavaScript, but I searched everywhere and I didn't find a solution.

Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Can you use jQuery?  It could make you problem a lot easier.

```
$('img').dbclick(function(){
   var image = $(this).clone(); 
   $('div#target').append(image);
});
```

The 'div#target' just needs to be the CSS selector for the div you want to paste to.

Answer (score 0):

This will append a new image to the place holder each time the user clicks on a specific image.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    setTimeout(function () {

        var imgView,
            imgPH = document.getElementById('imgPlaceHolder'),
            imgs = document.body.querySelectorAll('img');

        var showImageInPlaceHolder = function () {

            var imgView = document.createElement('img');
            imgView.src = this.src;
            imgPH.appendChild(imgView);
        };

        for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i += 1) {

            imgs[i].onclick = showImageInPlaceHolder;
        };
    }, 100);


</script>

<img src="/someimage1.jpg" />
<img src="/someimage2.jpg" />
<img src="/someimage3.jpg" />
<img src="/someimage4.jpg" />
<img src="/someimage5.jpg" />
<img src="/someimage6.jpg" />
<img src="/someimage7.jpg" />

<div id="imgPlaceHolder"></div>
```

Comment: It works fine, but I don't want the image to overwrite the previous one. Thank you anyways!

Comment: The image is not overwriting the old one. What the script is doing is pointing the image in the place hold src to the same src that the clicked image is pointing to.

Comment: Oh, understood. So this won't work for me, I need the script to let the user see all the images he/she has chosen.

Comment: Do you want to just append one after another, or do you want to save the chosen images and let the user click a button to view all the chosen images?

Comment: Ok, the code you're looking for is available. I've replaced the original code.